# Python error: "String index out of range"

Tags: python

I was making a Pig Latin translator in python (with all the specific rules) and here is my code:

```
print ("Enter some text here to be translated to Pig Latin: ");
text = input("> ");

wordlist = [];
letterlist = [];

for word in text:
    if word[0] != "a" and word[0] != "e" and word[0] != "i" and word[0] != "o" and word[0] != "u":
        if word[1] == "a" or word[1] == "e" or word[1] == "i" or word[1] == "o" or word[1] == "u":
            for number in range(1, len(word) - 1):
                letterlist.append(word[number]);
            letterlist.append(word[0]);
            letterlist.append("ay");
            new_word = "".join(letterlist);
            wordlist.append(new_word);
            letterlist = [];
        else:
            for number in range(2, len(word) - 2):
                letterlist.append(word[number]);
            letterlist.append(word[0]);
            letterlist.append(word[1]);
            letterlist.append("ay");
            new_word = "".join(letterlist);
            wordlist.append(new_word);
            letterlist = [];
    else:
        letterlist.append(word);
        letterlist.append("way");
        new_word = "".join(letterlist);
        wordlist.append(new_word);
        letterlist = [];

pigLatin = " ".join(wordlist);
print (pigLatin);
```

I get an error pointing towards the line:

```
if word[1] == "a" or word[1] == "e" or word[1] == "i" or word[1] == "o" or word[1] == "u":
```

saying that the string index is out of range. Please help!

Comment: If you enter a one-letter word, what would `word[1]` be?

Comment: how can you nest two compliment conditions within in one another ?

Comment: @jwodder Forget 1 letter input, The line `for word in text:` extracts 1 character from the string `text`. So this is an error for multi letter input too

Answer (score 1):

a couple of issues here. i'll structure my answer by adding #comments to your code.

generally speaking, you should first split the input from a string of characters into a list of "words" (groups of characters not including whitespace). in addition, before you check the value of word[1], you should add a block like `if len(word) < 2:; continue` so that you properly handle submissions which are only one character long (e.g. the letter "a").

```
print ("Enter some text here to be translated to Pig Latin: ");
text = input("> ");

wordlist = [];
letterlist = [];

for word in text: # how do you know that text will be separated into words?
# as of right now, text is a string of characters, not a list of words. you 
# should use something like words = text.split(), and then iterate over words. 
# .split() converts a string into a list of strings. by default it separates
# according to the whitespace between characters.
    if word[0] != "a" and word[0] != "e" and word[0] != "i" and word[0] != "o" and word[0] != "u":
        if word[1] == "a" or word[1] == "e" or word[1] == "i" or word[1] == "o" or word[1] == "u": 
# here's the problem referenced in your question. 
# since text is a string of characters, when you iterate over it with `for`,
# you will be looking at one character at a time. each character has only one 
# index, 0. for example 'e'[0] will return 'e', but 'e'[1] will throw an error,
# since there is no index 1.  

            for number in range(1, len(word) - 1):
                letterlist.append(word[number]);
            letterlist.append(word[0]);
            letterlist.append("ay");
            new_word = "".join(letterlist);
            wordlist.append(new_word);
            letterlist = [];
        else:
            for number in range(2, len(word) - 2):
                letterlist.append(word[number]);
            letterlist.append(word[0]);
            letterlist.append(word[1]);
            letterlist.append("ay");
            new_word = "".join(letterlist);
            wordlist.append(new_word);
            letterlist = [];
    else:
        letterlist.append(word);
        letterlist.append("way");
        new_word = "".join(letterlist);
        wordlist.append(new_word);
        letterlist = [];

pigLatin = " ".join(wordlist);
print (pigLatin);
```